# The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Could not make type inference in the call to join in linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I has the next query in sql

```
select * from Familia_Persona
inner join Personas on Personas.IdPersona = Familia_Persona.IdPersona
inner join Parentezco on Parentezco.IdParentezco = Familia_Persona.idParentezco
where Familia_Persona.idParentezco = 1
and Parentezco.idParentezco = 1
```

my objetive is convert in linq, I have tried following

```
var conocerPadre = from fp in db.Familia_Persona
                               join p in db.Personas on fp.IdPersona equals p.IdPersona
                               join pt in db.Parentezco on fp.Parentezco equals pt.IdParentezco
                               where (fp.IdFamilia == 1) && (pt.IdParentezco == 1)
                               select fp;
```

but, i has this error!

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Could not make type inference in the call to join

Comment: What are the data types of `fp.IdPersona`, `p.IdPersona`, `fp.Parentezco`, `pt.IdParentezco`? I would also recommend to keep naming consistent. You got `Familia_Persona.idParentezco` in sql and `fp.Parentezco` (see the missing "id").

Comment: hello @TomStein. Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: I would agree with @TomStein - are you using EF and is `Parentezco` a navigation property while `IdParentezco` is the foreign key? If you are using EF/EF Core, you shouldn't need `join`.